# How to replace Invalid Date Part (Day / Month) to default 01 if Year is valid

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Need Oracle SQL or stored procedure to convert invalid day or month in the date field to 01 if Year is a valid year. The input is in `varchar` format.

For example, if input value is `20132016` (MMDDYYYY), the `Year` is a valid value `2016`, now I have to check `Day` and `Month`.

In the example above, `Day` is also valid as it's `13`, but the month is invalid with a value of `20`. So I have to convert month to 01 (default). So the output expected is `01132016`.

I need this in my project to to predict someone age, So instead of inserting Null for invalid Date of Birth, I want to retain part of the date value importantly the Year.

I have a function to return valid date but this function does not return the expected result I am looking for.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUNC_CHK_DATE (P_INPUT IN VARCHAR2)
  Return Date
  Is
  v_date DATE := NULL;
  BEGIN
    V_DATE := TO_DATE( P_INPUT, 'YYYY/MM/DD');
    RETURN V_DATE;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RETURN null;
  END FUNC_CHK_DATE;
```

Comment: obviously you need to clean your data first before doing anything

Comment: The idea itself seems strange. Why would any system allow entering invalid dates, so you must guess the real date later? An invalid date should be rejected right away. Then, on invalid dates, you suppose there is just a typo in the day or month, but isn't it much more likely it's in the wrong format (e.g. DDMMYYYY = 31122017 or YYYYMMDD 20171231)? Then, when you think the day or month is wrong, you want to guess the age, but why then make them 01? Shouldn't you rather center (day = 15, month = 06) to get an average good guess?

Comment: Thanks for comment. I am migrating data from mainframe to oracle. It's 40 years  old data with alot of data issues. I was thinking about alternate way instead of inserting null for few specific date fields like dob, date of death etc, we can retain part of the date value instead of inserting null, also I m setting flag describing the date is updated and it's not the actual date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first mistake is here:

```
V_DATE := TO_DATE( P_INPUT, 'YYYY/MM/DD');
```

You say the expected format is `'MMDDYYYY'` (e.g. '20132016'). So why are you trying to convert a string formatted `'YYYY/MM/DD'`?

Then, when conversion fails, you are not even trying to detect the erroneous part and repair it, but simply return null. So how can this possibly return the desired date?

Let's start with an agorithm:

1. Check whether the input string is 8 digits exactly. If not, return null.
2. Convert to date. If that works, return the date.
3. Otherwise we'll check the year. Is it zero (which is not allowed in Oracle), we make it 0001.
4. Convert to date again. If that works, return the date.
5. Otherwise we'll check the month. Is it zero or greater than 12, we make it 01.
6. Convert to date again. If that works, return the date.
7. Otherwise the day is incorrect for the month and year, so we make it 01.
8. Convert to date again and return the date.

I'm using a loop for convenience here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_chk_date (p_input IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN DATE
IS
  v_date DATE;
  v_datestring CHAR(8);
BEGIN
  IF NOT REGEXP_LIKE(p_input, '^[[:digit:]]{8}$') THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;

  v_datestring := p_input;

  LOOP -- until conversion okay
    BEGIN
      v_date := TO_DATE(v_datestring, 'MMDDYYYY');
      EXIT; -- conversion okay
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SUBSTR(v_datestring, 5, 4) = '0000' THEN
        v_datestring := SUBSTR(v_datestring, 1, 4) || '0001';
      ELSIF TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(v_datestring, 3, 2)) NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 12 THEN
        v_datestring := SUBSTR(v_datestring, 1, 2) || '01' || SUBSTR(v_datestring, 5, 4);
      ELSE
        v_datestring := '01' || SUBSTR(v_datestring, 3, 6);
      END IF;
    END;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN V_DATE;
END FUNC_CHK_DATE;
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you. This is what I was looking for. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting your tests is one way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_chk_date (p_input IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN DATE
IS
    v_date   DATE := NULL;
BEGIN
    v_date   := TO_DATE (p_input, 'YYYY/MM/DD');
    RETURN v_date;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        BEGIN
            v_date   := TO_DATE (SUBSTR (p_input, 1, 4), 'YYYY');
            RETURN v_date;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS
            THEN
                RETURN NULL;
        END;
END func_chk_date;
```

Comment: Appreciate you response. Your function is good which is covering to return only Year for invalid date but it's not checking the valid month and day and convert them 01 if invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You create a function that traps the date errors that you've want to attempt correcting. The following is just one way.

```
create or replace function func_chk_date (date_string_in  varchar2
                                         ,date_format_in  varchar2 default 'mmddyyyy'
                                         )
  return date
  is
      bad_mon_e exception;
      PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(bad_mon_e, -01843);

      bad_day_e exception;
      PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(bad_day_e, -01839);

      bad_mon_day_e exception;
      PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(bad_mon_day_e, -01847);

      date_value_l  date;

      function fix_dd
        return varchar2
      is
      begin
          return substr(date_string_in,1,2) || '01' || substr(date_string_in,5);
      end fix_dd; 

      function fix_mm
        return varchar2
      is
      begin
          return '01' || substr(date_string_in,3);
      end fix_mm;       

  begin
      begin
          date_value_l:= to_date( date_string_in, date_format_in);
      exception
          when bad_mon_e then
                date_value_l:= func_chk_date (date_string_in   => fix_mm
                                             ,date_format_in   => date_format_in
                                             ); 
          when bad_day_e  
            or bad_mon_day_e then 
                date_value_l:=func_chk_date (date_string_in   => fix_dd
                                            ,date_format_in   => date_format_in
                                            ); 

      when others then 
           null;          -- << Actually a very bad idea at least log the error >>         
       end ;
    return date_value_l;
    exception 
        when  others then
            dbms_output.put_line('Other Error:'|| sqlerrm);
  end func_chk_date;
/
```

Some test data:

```
begin 
    dbms_output.put_line ('05052017 returned ' || func_chk_date('05052017'));
    dbms_output.put_line ('02292017 returned ' || func_chk_date('02292017'));
    dbms_output.put_line ('02292016 returned ' || func_chk_date('02292016'));  
    dbms_output.put_line ('13292016 returned ' || func_chk_date('13292016')); 
    dbms_output.put_line ('20402040 returned ' || func_chk_date('20402040'));
    dbms_output.put_line ('0505yyyy returned ' || func_chk_date('0505yyyy'));
end ;
```

The function works as is but is limited to the date format "mmddyyyy". If you want a different format you'll need to modify the fix-mm and/or the fix_dd functions. Also this is a recursive routine so you'll need to guarantee there is a exit path.